# PHP can't assign smarty variable

Tags: php, smarty

I'm trying to assign some variable in smarty using PHP but the smarty variable return NULL. Here is my code :

```
{php}
$GLOBALS['smarty']->assign("new_var", "somevalue");
{/php}

{$new_var|@var_dump}
```

The code above will return `NULL`
I don't know what is happening.

Comment: Try this syntax `{global put=foo value=$bar}` and get details [here](https://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=54634)

Comment: @Rahul I tried and my page show up a blank page. I need to use PHP to assign

Comment: You're assigning it within the view which is (presumably) after all assigned variables are turned into `$vars` why not just do `$new_var = 'somevalue';` in the php block?

Comment: @apokryfos Because I need to use it in JavaScript. Can I use it like `var js_var = '{php} echo $new_var; {/php}';` ?

Comment: if you replace the `{php}$GLOBALS...{/php}` part in your shared code with a simple variable declaration you can go on and use `$new_var` within your view as normal wherever you want.

Comment: I tried to use it in JavaScript block but it return a blank page

Comment: "_it return a blank page_" You did inspect the page right? because it's normal to have a blank page if you dump in a script tag

Comment: @cbaconnier Yes I did check, because I have some html in it that's why the page is crashing. I don't dump in the script tag

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use a PHP file ?

```
require("application/libraries/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php"); // Smarty class Smarty                   
        $smarty = new Smarty();
        $smarty->assign('new_var' => $phpvar);
        $smarty->display('blabla.tpl');
```